# Expectation of a random walk series does not match Monto Carlo simulation

Tags: probability

I have a question given as below:

Suppose I get an random walk series: $x (i) = 0.1\text{ or }-0.099$, $i=1,2,…$, where $x(i)$ takes value $0$ or $1$ with a probability of $50\%$, and each $x(i)$ is independently valued.

Now I form a new series $y(i)=\prod_{j=1}^i\left(1+x(j)\right)$, and I want to know the expectation of $y(i)$ when $i\to\infty$.

$$\text{Exp}(y(i))=\text{Exp}(\prod_{j=1}^i(1+x(j)) )=\prod_{j=1}^i(1+\text{Exp}(x(j))) =\prod_{j=1}^i(1+(0.1-0.099)/2),$$
when $i\to\infty$, $\text{Exp}(y(i))\to\infty$.

However, when I do Monte Carlo simulation to generate $1000 y(i)$ series and let $i=10000$, I find that $y(10000)\to0$, where I get a contradiction.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  Also, do not [post simultaneously](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/195786/expectation-of-a-random-walk-series-does-not-match-monto-carlo-simulation) here and on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $E[Y_i] \to \infty$ does not imply that $Y_i \to \infty$ almost surely.
See even my [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/412546/17459) of when $E[Y_i] \to \infty$ but $Y_i \to -\infty$ almost surely.

In this case some explanation (which can lead to a proof) is that the number of $X_i$ that are $0.1$ minus the number that are $-.099$ is a symmetric random walk and we should expect about the same number of each. However, for any $x \in (0,1)$ we know $(1+x)(1-x) = 1-x^2 < 1$. Thus a $0.1$ realization doesn't really cancel out a $-.099$ realization, that is the multiplication is biased towards zero.